# AppScript Array Filter (String) not filtering empty values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Trying to filter out empty values from getRange values but still giving me all data.
I've tried the following but still not what I expected.

Data array logs the following: 123,,,444,,,331,323,,,,,,5443

```
var list = source.getRange("sheet!A1:J1:).getValues().filter(String);
```

or using callback function

```
list.filter(function(f) {return f[0] !=='';})
```

Result is still the same  123,,,444,,,331,323,,,,,,5443
What did I missed here?

Comment: remove the [0] in the filter function. it should work fine.

Comment: Im still getting the empty values after I omit the [0].

Answer (score 0):

After your comment i am not sure if the data you get is an array or an string:

> Data array logs the following: 123,,,444,,,331,323,,,,,,5443

For the array case: `[123,,,444,,,331,323,,,,,,5443]`

```js
const list = [123,,,444,,,331,323,,,,,,5443]
const result = list.filter(Boolean)

console.log(result)
```

For the string case: `123,,,444,,,331,323,,,,,,5443`

```js
const list = '123,,,444,,,331,323,,,,,,5443'
const result = list.split(',').filter(Boolean).map(Number)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I tried this approach and did not work. I'm getting my data from spreadsheet via getRange + getVaues()

Comment: Improved answer based on your comment